# How to retrieve Google Form and its 240 responses that have disappeared

Tags: google-forms

Please help me retrieve my Google Form and its 240 responses have disappeared.
Those 240 responses have been collected over 2 years as part of my thesis survey. I could access the form and responses till Jun-2021.

I am not a technical person... so please advice on the type of details required to get expert help.
I own the form and used gmail-id to host and circulate the same.

Grateful for your help.

Additional info:

1. I have one gmail-id. I do use Gmail host to access other mail-ids.
2. Yes, I did link Google Form to Google Sheet. Unfortunately even that is missing.
3. I have downloaded responses in between, but not recently.
4. Form has been static since feb2020 ... since it is a survey & should be consistent through the study period.  I do have offline copy in XL form.

Comment: It looks that you used a second account to edit the question, if that is correct please follow the directions on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to ask that your accounts be merged. Regarding the additional details, please indicate if you linked your form to a Google spreadsheet, if you have made changes to your form, if you have made copies of it.

Comment: You can use the [Contact Us](/contact) form to have your accounts merged, so that you can freely edit your question.